# Error handler function stops error logging

Tags: php, error-handling

I have this simple code in the first few lines of my script and it works real good in logging errors until I add the error handler function. My error handling function is doing quite a good job and I haven't found any thing wrong with it expect this.

```
ini_set("log_errors" , "1");
ini_set("error_log" , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/logs/Errors.log.txt");
```

Is this thing a default working of php that error logging stops as soon as you start error handling?

If yes, how can I overcome it?

My error handler function might help to.

```
function userErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile = '', $errline = 0, $errcontext = array())
{
    // Check if the error code is not included in error_reporting
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Restore default handlers to prevent errors in errors
    restore_error_handler();
    if (function_exists('restore_exception_handler'))
    {
        restore_exception_handler();
    }

    // Load error page
    require('_errors/error.php');
    exit();
}
set_error_handler('userErrorHandler');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So it overwrites default handler and the error logging stops, also their is no way to overcome that. But there is something else that can be done here and results the same output as expected.

```
function userErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile = '', $errline = 0, $errcontext = array())
{
    // Getting error type
    $errorType = array (
            E_ERROR            => 'ERROR',
            E_WARNING        => 'WARNING',
            E_PARSE          => 'PARSING ERROR',
            E_NOTICE         => 'NOTICE',
            E_CORE_ERROR     => 'CORE ERROR',
            E_CORE_WARNING   => 'CORE WARNING',
            E_COMPILE_ERROR  => 'COMPILE ERROR',
            E_COMPILE_WARNING => 'COMPILE WARNING',
            E_USER_ERROR     => 'USER ERROR',
            E_USER_WARNING   => 'USER WARNING',
            E_USER_NOTICE    => 'USER NOTICE',
            E_STRICT         => 'STRICT NOTICE',
            E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  => 'RECOVERABLE ERROR'
            );

    if (array_key_exists($errno, $errorType)) {
        $err = $errorType[$errno];
    } else {
        $err = 'CAUGHT EXCEPTION';
    }

    // Logging error to a certain file
    $file           = ini_get('error_log');
    $error_string   = "[" . date("d-M-Y H:i:s", $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . '] PHP ' . $err . '::' . $errstr . " in " . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] . " on line " . $errline . "\r\n";
    error_log($error_string, 3, $file);

    // Check if the error code is not included in error_reporting
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Restore default handlers to prevent errors in errors
    restore_error_handler();
    if (function_exists('restore_exception_handler'))
    {
        restore_exception_handler();
    }

    // Load error page
    require('_errors/error.php');
    exit();
}
set_error_handler('userErrorHandler');
```

The same that I wanted to do :)

Read the complete working here: http://blog.abhishekg.com/2012/06/error-handling-in-php-with-error-logger-working/

Answer (score 0):

When you start using `set_error_handler()`, the built-in error handling will not take place, with probably the exception of parse errors (but only if the `error_log` is defined outside of your PHP script itself, such as `.htaccess`).

The same goes for the default error echoing that PHP does.

**Update**

The return value of `set_error_handler()` returns `NULL` when the previous error handler was the built-in one, so it's not possible to call it with the arguments your own function has received.

Comment: all I am using is restore_error_handler() and restore_exception_handler() to do the working. Should I post my error handling function for better understanding?

Comment: @abhig hmm, why are you using `restore_error_handler()` if you're not defining your own? :)

Comment: hmm.. actually its not my own script. I borrowed it from someone. I am still trying to understand it completely

Comment: @abhig no, because when you restore the error handler at the time of error, the error has already happened ;-)

Comment: @abhig maybe if you keep the old error handler you can pass it all the arguments you've received. Maybe that will work

Comment: @abhig updated my answer, I think you're out of luck, but at least we tried :)